# Why is the form showing errors?

Tags: python, web2py

This form is meant to take an answer from the user in the view and when the form is submitted the users answer should match the correct_answer variable to pass and correct. But even when the user inputs the correct answer the form shows errors. What am I doing wrong?

**Default.py**

```
def practice_game():

    import random
    db_length = db(db.verb.id > 0).count()
    verb = db().select(db.verb.ALL,orderby='<random>',limitby= (0,1))[0]
    random_int = random.randint(1,6)
    global correct_answer
    tense = 'present'
    if random_int == 1:
        correct_answer = str(verb.verb_present_je)
    elif random_int == 2:
        correct_answer = str(verb.verb_present_tu)
    elif random_int == 3:
        correct_answer = str(verb.verb_present_il)
    elif random_int == 4:
        correct_answer = str(verb.verb_present_nous)
    elif random_int == 5:
        correct_answer = str(verb.verb_present_vous)
    else:
        correct_answer = str(verb.verb_present_ils)

    form=FORM('Your answer:',
              INPUT(_name='user_answer', requires=IS_EQUAL_TO(correct_answer)),
              INPUT(_type='submit'))
    if form.accepts(request,session):
        response.flash = 'form accepted'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
    else:
        response.flash = 'please fill the form'
    return dict(form=form, counter=session.counter, correct_answer=correct_answer, verb=verb, tense=tense, pronoun=pronoun, current_user=auth.user.first_name)
```

Comment: What's actually in `form.errors`?  Why is it blowing up?  You've got at least one validation check in your form; perhaps the validation is failing?

Comment: Ive just changed the validation to IS_NOT_EMPTY and written the new line of code:
'if form.accepts(request,session):
        if request.vars.user_answer == correct_answer:
            response.flash = 'form accepted'
        else:
            response.flash = 'wrong'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
    else:
        response.flash = 'please fill the form''

And it now shows "wrong" everytime. Something wrong with comparing the user_answer with the correct_answer.

Comment: ...Right.  But that doesn't answer my question - what was in `form.errors`?

Comment: This proves that there is something wrong with the 'correct_answer' variable. I have no idea what is in form.errors.

Comment: ...So why don't you print it out?  That's what I'm getting at here.  You shouldn't be suppressing what `form.errors` contains.

Comment: Well ill be honest i have no idea how to find out. Sorry im new to this and im pretty sure form.errors only shows when the form doesnt meet the validation rule.

Comment: How are you determining what answer to enter into the form? Are you showing the value of `correct_answer` in the view and then just entering that? If so, in most cases that will not work because when the form is submitted, you select a new random correct answer, which will be different from the previously displayed correct answer 5 out of 6 times.

Comment: That is exactly what Im doing! You're a genius. Any ideas how I could fix this? @Anthony

Answer (score 0):

The form is self-submitting, so the action is called twice -- once when the blank form is loaded, and again when the form is submitted. On each call, you generate a new random correct answer. The correct answer initially displayed on the page (which you end up entering in the form and submitting) will not necessarily be the same as the correct answer generated (and validated) when the form is submitted (they should match up one sixth of the time by chance).

To avoid this problem, you can store the initial correct answer in the session, and use that for validation:

```
form=FORM('Your answer:',
          INPUT(_name='user_answer',
                requires=IS_EQUAL_TO(session.correct_answer)),
          INPUT(_type='submit'))
if form.accepts(request,session):
    response.flash = 'form accepted'
elif form.errors:
    response.flash = 'form has errors'
else:
    response.flash = 'please fill the form'
session.correct_answer = correct_answer
```